# location.hash result is returning false

Tags: jquery, url

I am trying to test against the location hash in the URL on page load.

The example URL is domain.com/#/case-studies/

Below I am getting the first part of the hash location, it will output `/case-studies/` which is correct.
However the second console log return false, even though it seems correct.

```
var hashLoad = location.hash.slice(1);

console.log('hash = ' + hashLoad);
console.log(hashLoad == '/case-studies/');
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks for your help

Comment: What does console logging hashLoad give you, it should be easy to figure out wether the strings are the same ?

Comment: Try to `console.log(hashLoad.split(''))` to make sure there are no extra characters in there.

Comment: @adeneo My first console.log outputs /case-studies/, which is what i am testing against and what i see as being true

Comment: Then try `console.log(hashLoad.trim() == '/case-studies/');`

Comment: @adeneo .trim worked! Thanks. Why was that?

Comment: You had white space in the hash. You can catch it by highlighting the value in the console, and you'll see if there is any whitespace highlighted as well, that's the easiest way to verify that what's printed in the console is the same string.

Comment: @zizther why, because see Rocket's comment ;)

Comment: Slice was the wrong thing to use, I am now using split which gives more concise results